# Which value do I have to return in COleDropTarget::OnDrop() when handling multiple files?

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, drag-and-drop, ole

I made my MFC application a drop target by deriving the class `CDropTarget` from [`COleDropTarget`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4w4z9dwh.aspx) and overriding [all necessary functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sb1hcbey.aspx). Everything works as expected. However, the return value of [OnDrop()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b849s138.aspx) confuses me. Its description reads:

> Nonzero if the drop is successful; otherwise 0.

I don't understand what "successful" means if multiple files are dropped on my application.
For example, consider the following implementation:

```
BOOL CDropTarget::OnDrop(CWnd* pWnd, COleDataObject* pDataObj, DROPEFFECT tDropEffect, CPoint tPoint)
{
    // I left out declaration/definition of hDrop and path for reasons of clarity.
    [...]

    UINT numHandledFiles = 0;

    // Determine the number of dropped files.
    UINT numDroppedFiles = DragQueryFile(hDrop, 0xFFFFFFFF, NULL, 0);

    // Iterate over all dropped files.
    for (UINT n = 0; n < numDroppedFiles; n++)
    {
        // Get the path of the current file from the HDROP structure.
        if (DragQueryFile(hDrop, n, path, PATH_MAX) > 0)
        {
            // Try to handle each dropped file in my function handleFile().
            // It returns true if a file could be handled and false otherwise.
            // (The latter happens if a file with the wrong type was dropped.)
            if (handleFile(path))
                numHandledFiles++;
        }
    }

    return ?  // See description below.
}
```

Now assume that my function `handleFile()` can only handle *.png* files
and that multiple files with different file types are dropped on my application at once.

How do I replace `return ?` in the above code correctly? I see two options:

```
return numHandledFiles > 0;                 // At least one file could be handled.
```

And:

```
return numHandledFiles == numDroppedFiles;  // All files could be handled.
```

I tried both, but when dropping files from Windows Explorer or Total Commander on my application,
I don't notice any difference at all. What effect does the return value have?

Comment: It simply determines the return value of DoDragDrop() in the code that started the drag so it can tell whether or not the drag succeeded.  It *might* use this value to do some post-drag cleanup.  This is very unusual, especially so when dragging files.  Implicit is that you have no idea what this code looks like, so you can never be 100% sure what effect it might have.  Given the very low odds that it does, and that you checked that it didn't, best thing to do is to stop worrying about it.

Comment: @HansPassant: Well, this is my first time implementing a drop target. I'm quite sure I did several things wrong, so I tried to understand at least this. Maybe I'm thinking too much ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When reading MFC documentation leaves you puzzled you should turn to the Windows SDK documentation, as recommended in the link you provided: *"For more information, see [IDropTarget::Drop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms687242) in the Windows SDK."*:

> On return, must contain one of the [DROPEFFECT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693457) flags, which indicates what the result of the drop operation **would be**.

Note that `IDropTarget::Drop` more closely resembles [COleDropTarget::OnDropEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/a58c9a48-6a93-4357-b078-4594df258311.aspx#coledroptarget__ondropex), which you should be implementing instead of `COleDropTarget::OnDrop`. There is no strict rule for the case you describe. However, the `DROPEFFECT` should match application behavior (i.e. accept or reject).

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm a bit puzzled (again). Your quoted text refers to the parameter `DWORD *pdwEffect` of the `Drop()` function. That is not the return value. The return value is a `HRESULT` for `Drop()` and `BOOL` for my `OnDrop()`. I read that `OnDrop()` is for simple drops, which I thought would be sufficient in my case. Why is it better to use `OnDropEx()`?

Comment: @honk: In terms of C++, the `HRESULT` is the return value of `Drop()`. However, that's just an artifact of COM. In the majority of cases, COM interface members return an error/success code in addition to the true return value(s) (those that are decorated using the `[out]` IDL attribute). As for `OnDrop()` vs. `OnDropEx()`: Like many convenience implementations in the MFC, they add complexity without substantial benefit. In this specific case, it also hides important information (e.g. which `DROPEFFECT` relates to the `BOOL` return value of `OnDop()`).

Comment: Thank you, I understand your answer much better now! I think I will go for `OnDropEx()` then. However, I'm still unsure which `DROPEFFECT` to use. My application just collects file paths in order to read the files later. So, I'm neither doing a `COPY` or `MOVE` operation and therefore decided for `NONE`. Which one would be (most) correct?